# Using height-auto for Bootstrap 3 input fields

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm finding the only way to have **editable** input fields is to include the height-auto class on them.

**By not including this class, I cannot enter any input into the input fields.**

The height-auto makes the input field basically twice the size as if I don't have it in and looks a little awkward.

If I need to include this class to make the fields editable, fine then; otherwise can someone please inform me how I can make the fields editable without using this class?

Note that the first field in the form below is with the height-auto class. The rest are not.
[image]

### EDIT #2 - Pertinent CSS CODE

Below, is the CSS code which I did not create. I'm sure the issue lies in here somewhere. If anyone can let me know where that might be, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #686868;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #dc3836;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(220, 56, 54, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(220, 56, 54, 0.6);
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #777777;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #777777;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #777777;
}
.form-control[disabled],
.form-control[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  opacity: 1;
}
textarea.form-control {
  height: auto;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type="date"] {
  line-height: 31px;
}
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.radio,
.checkbox {
  display: block;
  min-height: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.radio label,
.checkbox label {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio input[type="radio"],
.radio-inline input[type="radio"],
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"],
.checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.radio + .radio,
.checkbox + .checkbox {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.radio-inline,
.checkbox-inline {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio-inline + .radio-inline,
.checkbox-inline + .checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"][disabled],
input[type="checkbox"][disabled],
.radio[disabled],
.radio-inline[disabled],
.checkbox[disabled],
.checkbox-inline[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] input[type="radio"],
fieldset[disabled] input[type="checkbox"],
fieldset[disabled] .radio,
fieldset[disabled] .radio-inline,
fieldset[disabled] .checkbox,
fieldset[disabled] .checkbox-inline {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.input-sm {
  height: 27px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
select.input-sm {
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 27px;
}
textarea.input-sm,
select[multiple].input-sm {
  height: auto;
}
.input-lg {
  height: 41px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
select.input-lg {
  height: 41px;
  line-height: 41px;
}
textarea.input-lg,
select[multiple].input-lg {
  height: auto;
}
.has-feedback {
  position: relative;
}
.has-feedback .form-control {
  padding-right: 38.75px;
}
.has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 31px;
  text-align: center;
}
.has-success .help-block,
.has-success .control-label,
.has-success .radio,
.has-success .checkbox,
.has-success .radio-inline,
.has-success .checkbox-inline {
  color: #468847;
}
.has-success .form-control {
  border-color: #468847;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-success .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #356635;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #7aba7b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #7aba7b;
}
.has-success .input-group-addon {
  color: #468847;
  border-color: #468847;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
.has-success .form-control-feedback {
  color: #468847;
}
.has-warning .help-block,
.has-warning .control-label,
.has-warning .radio,
.has-warning .checkbox,
.has-warning .radio-inline,
.has-warning .checkbox-inline {
  color: #c09853;
}
.has-warning .form-control {
  border-color: #c09853;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-warning .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #a47e3c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #dbc59e;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #dbc59e;
}
.has-warning .input-group-addon {
  color: #c09853;
  border-color: #c09853;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
}
.has-warning .form-control-feedback {
  color: #c09853;
}
.has-error .help-block,
.has-error .control-label,
.has-error .radio,
.has-error .checkbox,
.has-error .radio-inline,
.has-error .checkbox-inline {
  color: #b94a48;
}
.has-error .form-control {
  border-color: #b94a48;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-error .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #953b39;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
}
.has-error .input-group-addon {
  color: #b94a48;
  border-color: #b94a48;
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
.has-error .form-control-feedback {
  color: #b94a48;
}
.form-control-static {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.help-block {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #848484;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .form-inline .input-group > .form-control {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-inline .control-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .form-inline .radio,
  .form-inline .checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .form-inline .radio input[type="radio"],
  .form-inline .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
    top: 0;
  }
}
.form-horizontal .control-label,
.form-horizontal .radio,
.form-horizontal .checkbox,
.form-horizontal .radio-inline,
.form-horizontal .checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
.form-horizontal .radio,
.form-horizontal .checkbox {
  min-height: 22px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-left: -6px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-control-static {
  padding-top: 7px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
.form-horizontal .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  /*border-radius: 4px;*/
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-default {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border-color: #bfbfbf;
}
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  border-color: #a1a1a1;
}
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-default.disabled,
.btn-default[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,
.btn-default.disabled:hover,
.btn-default[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
.btn-default.disabled:focus,
.btn-default[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.disabled:active,
.btn-default[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
.btn-default.disabled.active,
.btn-default[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border-color: #bfbfbf;
}
.btn-default .badge {
  color: #e4e4e4;
  background-color: #333333;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #c31318;
  border-color: #ac1115;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #9e0f13;
  border-color: #740b0e;
}
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #c31318;
  border-color: #ac1115;
}
.btn-primary .badge {
  color: #c31318;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-success {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  /*border-color: #4cae4c;*/
}
.btn-success:hover,
.btn-success:focus,
.btn-success:active,
.btn-success.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #47a447;
  border-color: #398439;
}
.btn-success:active,
.btn-success.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-success.disabled,
.btn-success[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success,
.btn-success.disabled:hover,
.btn-success[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:hover,
.btn-success.disabled:focus,
.btn-success[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:focus,
.btn-success.disabled:active,
.btn-success[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:active,
.btn-success.disabled.active,
.btn-success[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success.active {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #4cae4c;
}
.btn-success .badge {
  color: #5cb85c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-info {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
}
.btn-info:hover,
.btn-info:focus,
.btn-info:active,
.btn-info.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-info {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #39b3d7;
  border-color: #269abc;
}
.btn-info:active,
.btn-info.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-info {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-info.disabled,
.btn-info[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-info,
.btn-info.disabled:hover,
.btn-info[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-info:hover,
.btn-info.disabled:focus,
.btn-info[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-info:focus,
.btn-info.disabled:active,
.btn-info[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-info:active,
.btn-info.disabled.active,
.btn-info[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-info.active {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
}
.btn-info .badge {
  color: #5bc0de;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-warning {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  border-color: #eea236;
}
.btn-warning:hover,
.btn-warning:focus,
.btn-warning:active,
.btn-warning.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-warning {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ed9c28;
  border-color: #d58512;
}
.btn-warning:active,
.btn-warning.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-warning {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-warning.disabled,
.btn-warning[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning,
.btn-warning.disabled:hover,
.btn-warning[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning:hover,
.btn-warning.disabled:focus,
.btn-warning[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning:focus,
.btn-warning.disabled:active,
.btn-warning[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning:active,
.btn-warning.disabled.active,
.btn-warning[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-warning.active {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  border-color: #eea236;
}
.btn-warning .badge {
  color: #f0ad4e;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-danger {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #f0302d;
  border-color: #ee1915;
}
.btn-danger:hover,
.btn-danger:focus,
.btn-danger:active,
.btn-danger.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-danger {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #e41410;
  border-color: #b9100d;
}
.btn-danger:active,
.btn-danger.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-danger {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-danger.disabled,
.btn-danger[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger,
.btn-danger.disabled:hover,
.btn-danger[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:hover,
.btn-danger.disabled:focus,
.btn-danger[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:focus,
.btn-danger.disabled:active,
.btn-danger[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger:active,
.btn-danger.disabled.active,
.btn-danger[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-danger.active {
  background-color: #f0302d;
  border-color: #ee1915;
}
.btn-danger .badge {
  color: #f0302d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-link {
  color: #c31318;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-link,
.btn-link:active,
.btn-link[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-link {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-link,
.btn-link:hover,
.btn-link:focus,
.btn-link:active {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.btn-link:hover,
.btn-link:focus {
  color: #7d0c0f;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.btn-link[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-link:hover,
.btn-link[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-link:focus {
  color: #777777;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-lg,
.btn-group-lg > .btn {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.btn-sm,
.btn-group-sm > .btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.btn-xs,
.btn-group-xs > .btn {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.btn-block + .btn-block {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
input[type="submit"].btn-block,
input[type="reset"].btn-block,
input[type="button"].btn-block {
  width: 100%;
}
```

### Edit

Here is some HTML code..

```
<div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txtJournalVoucherJVNumber">Journal Voucher #:</label>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control height-auto" id="txtJournalVoucherJVNumber" />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtJournalVoucherTotalDebitFrom">Total Debit From:</label>
                                                            <div class="controls form-inline">
                                                                <input class="input-small" id="txtJournalVoucherTotalDebitFrom" placeholder="From Date" type="text" />
                                                                <label for="txtJournalVoucherTotalDebitTo">To:</label>
                                                                <input class="input-small" id="txtJournalVoucherTotalDebitTo" placeholder="To Date" type="text" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code as this is not the normal behaviour of the input fields. Something in your code must be causing this.

Comment: It sounds like you have some javascript tied to that class, so you may have to override the class CSS with an additional class. Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that there is another css file that is causing the problem from some other plugin. Once I commented that out, it worked fine.